# TYPO3 10.4: Menu of subpages with image

Tags: typo3, fluid, typo3-10.x, fluid-styled-content

I would like to expand the content element "menu of subpages" with images from page resources.

In TYPO3 8.7 the following code did everything i needed:

```
<f:if condition="{menu}">
    <ul class="pagemenu-img">
        <f:for each="{menu}" as="page">
            <li>
                <a href="{page.link}"{f:if(condition: page.target, then: ' target="{page.target}"')} title="{page.title}">
                    <f:image src="fileadmin/{page.files.0.originalFile.identifier}" />
                    <span>{page.title}</span>
                </a>
            </li>
        </f:for>
    </ul>
</f:if>
```

With TYPO3 10.4 this isn't working anymore.
Is there another way? Preferably without using VHS.

Comment: why don't you just create a new filed on your pages table where the user can add images? (extend the pages table)

Comment: I think for this issue there is no need to create a new field. It worked well in the past.

Comment: What means "this isn't working anymore"? Do you get an exception? What value has `page.files.0.originalFile.identifier`?

Comment: I recieve the following error:
Supplied file object type TYPO3\CMS\Core\Resource\Folder for fileadmin/ must be File or FileReference.
It works when every subpage has an image uploaded. I included an if statement... now it works either way

Comment: And `<f:image src="fileadmin/" />` doesn't throw an exception under TYPO3 v8.7?

Comment: Hi there! Could you please consider marking the question as solved if you found a solution? thank you.

Answer (score 1):

It's still working.

I have tested your HTML-Template and the result is as expected:
[image]

Your problems seem to be something other...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there were some pages which didn't have any images with them...

You should therefore check if there is an image present:
[and get rid of the hardcoded fileadmin/ link there by< just using `{page.files.0.originalFile}`]

```
<f:if condition="{menu}">
    <ul class="pagemenu-img">
        <f:for each="{menu}" as="page">
            <li>
                <a href="{page.link}"{f:if(condition: page.target, then: ' target="{page.target}"')} title="{page.title}">

                    <f:if condition="{page.files.0}">
                        <f:image image="{page.files.0.originalFile}" />
                    </f:if>

                    <span>{page.title}</span>
                </a>
            </li>
        </f:for>
    </ul>
</f:if>
```